# Graph of $\frac 1x$ and what is an inverse relationship?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, curves

[image]

I understand that the graph of $\frac 1x$ is not a line as it does not agree with the form $y=mx+c$ and the properties of a linear relationship. However I'm struggling intuitively to understand this. When we graph $y=x$, we find as $x$ doubles $y$ also doubles and so on. They have a proportional relationship. As $x$ doubles in $\frac 1x$, the $y$ values half and so on. This is an indirectly proportional relationship. My intuition makes me think that it should also be a line but sloped the other way. However this is not the case. Why? I think my problem lies in intuitively understanding why the graph of $\frac 1x$ increases exponentially. As when $x$ doubles $y$ halves it doesn't make sense to me why the curve increases so rapidly.

Comment: Intuition is a useful guide in mathematics, and it develops by working through issues like this. Best of luck.

Comment: If you approximate $\frac{1}{x}$ at any point with a line, it will be sloped negatively. Maybe that helps? But I don't understand why you say “the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ increases exponentially”—I don't see any place it increases at all, let alone “exponentially”

Comment: You got several thoughtful answers on this [very closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658294/why-is-the-graph-of-frac-1x-a-curve?rq=1) yesterday. What was insufficient about them?

Comment: a line "sloped the other way" would be just of the form $y = -mx+c$. Still not something like $xy = 1$....

Comment: I imagine you are in high school. Therefore, I doubt that you have already seen logarithm function. But when you will have seen it, the transformation from $xy=1$ to $\underbrace{\log(x)}_X+\underbrace{\log(y)}_Y=0$ will realize your dreams !

Comment: @JeanMarie But it seems OP has already learnt about derivatives ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643282/are-turning-points-and-stationary-points-the-same)); it would be rather unusual if OP hasn't seen logs

Comment: @Golden Ratio You may be right !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x):=1/x$ does not change *exponentially*.  An exponential function would be of the form $g(x):=ab^x$ for $b>0$.

You have already identified that as $x$ doubles, $y$ halves. Alternatively, you could say as $x$ halves, $y$ doubles; this observation alone should give you a sense why $f$ spikes so rapidly near the origin.

You ask why $f$ does not look like a line. Note that a linear function has a constant rate of change, so in essence, you are asking why $f$ doesn't have a constant rate of change.

Note that $f$ changes much more at smaller values of $|x|$. For instance, $$f(1)-f(2)=1-1/2=1/2>1/6=1/2-1/3=f(2)-f(3).$$ In words, this says if I gave you a cake and took half of it away from you, you would be left with more cake than if I gave you half the cake and took a third of the cake away from you.

Answer (score 1):

In the [precursor Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4658383/21813), I suggested that you may be unclear about **inverse proportionality** $(xy=7)$ versus **direct proportionality** $(y=7x)$.

In this Question, though, you appear to be conflating

- **inverse proportionality** $(xy=7)$

  tripling $x$ correspondingly divides $y$ by three
- **negative direct proportionality** $(y=-7x)$

  tripling $x$ correspondingly triples $y;$ $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs
- **exponential decrease** $(y=7e^{-5x})$

  $y$ is undergoing constant percentage decay.

For $x>0:$

[image]

A key difference between **positive inverse proportionality** $(xy=7)$ and **a negative linear relationship** $(y=-5x+7)$ is that in the former, $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, so as $x$ gets large, $y$ doesn't get to decrease beyond the $x$-axis (its floor), so its continued decrease significantly slows down.